# In a Flask App, where should Celery be instantiated?

Tags: python, flask, celery, message-queue

I have a Flask app, which is a very basic app with a POST handler and some DB insertions. The DB insertions are set as tasks using Celery. If I put my Celery instance creation and tasks definition in `tasks.py` file, and call the functions from my `main.py` file (which also has the Flask app creation), I get an `out of context error`. The tasks in the `tasks.py` file in turn call a DB class that does the DB insertions. How do I properly create the Celery instance and make sure it has the Flask context?

This is how the structure roughly resembles:

1. main.py = Flask app creation, routes handling and tasks.delay calls.
2. tasks.py = Celery instance creation and task definitions.
3. DB = Inserts.

I want everything to work in the same context.

Comment: These links helped me http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask & http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/celery-and-the-flask-application-factory-pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flask docs [suggest](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/celery/) subclassing Celery's Task class and wrapping task execution in a Flask app context. So in `task.py` if your Flask app instance is named `app` and your Celery instance is named `celery`, you would replace `celery`'s Task attribute with the new subclass:

```
TaskBase = celery.Task
class ContextTask(TaskBase):
    abstract = True
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with app.app_context():
            return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
celery.Task = ContextTask
```

Comment: Thanks. I read in a post somewhere that I need to create a Flask instance in the file where I a initiate Celery. When I do that it works. But isn't that redundant?

Comment: Your web server runs separately from your celery workers, so it's not redundant to have two different instances of the flask app. You can avoid code duplication by using a [function to create app instances](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/config/#configuration-best-practices) (also known as an [app factory](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/appfactories/)).

Comment: Yes indeed I managed to do this. But I had some trouble importing the factory if my app was nested into multiple levels of folders. As in using Blueprints. Thanks!